# ARKit, Xcode, and iOS 11 upgrade

Tags: macos, xcode

I have **El Capital 10.11.6** and I do not wish to upgrade, however I need to clarify whether this means I cannot download and experiment with **ARKit**?

The latest **Xcode** version that is compatible with El Capitan is **8.2.1** but when trying to download ARKit, it suggests using Xcode 9.x so I wonder if this is just a suggestion or absolute requirement?

In other words, the fact that I would like to remain in El Capitan **and** Xcode 8.2.1 definitely means that I can never download and use ARKit. **Correct?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to develop ARKit apps **you need to use Xcode 9.x**. Xcide 8.2.x does not include ARKit.

From Apple's [Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/):

> Get Started with ARKit
>
> Xcode 9 and iOS 11 Download iOS 11 and the latest version of Xcode 9,
>   which includes the iOS 11 SDK to build AR features in your app today.